# Suggestion to give more information and badges based on answers

Tags: feature-request, badges, accepted-answer, profile-page, badge-request

Just a suggestion to give more information based on accepted answers.

1. Total posts marked as the accepted answered
2. Percentage of [total posts that are accepted answer] / [total non-question posts] * 100
3. Badge for 50 accepted answers, 100, 500, 1000, etc... (Make it high enough that even Jon Skeet has something to shoot for)
4. Not sure how the specialist badges works but could it weigh an answer as like +10 towards getting the badge vs just a post being +1?  SO might already do this.